Groupby, count and list the counted item in pandas
I've the following DF:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'C1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], 
    'C2': [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]})

After a groupby:
df.groupby('C1').count()

-------
C1 | C2
-------
A  | 3
B  | 2

But the result I want to get is:
--------------
C1 | C2 | List
--------------  
A  | 3  | [5,15,25]
B  | 2  | [10,20]

I want to get the list of the elements counted in the groupby operation COUNT.
Is it possible?
